# How to add new a new property to an object in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
    var fruits = [];
        fruits[0] = {name:"apple", stock:"1box"}
        fruits[1] = {name:"banana", stock:"2box"}
        fruits[2] = {name:"banana", stock:"3box"}
```

so in case of this object
is there any simple way to add new field inside of list like this?
for example

```
fruits[0] = {name:"apple", stock:"1box", **taste:"good"**}
```

like this.

i tried create new template and copy original data and paste to the new template, for example

```
function fruit_2(name, stock, taste){
this.name = name;
this.stock = stock;
this.taste = taste;
}//create new template
```

and re-add element from the fruit[0] and then fruit[1] to new template like this

but i was wondering if there is easier or faster way.

thank you for reading my question.

i will appreciate any help! thanks!

Comment: `fruits[0].taste = "good"`

Comment: It is unclear as to what output are you looking for. What should be the end result?

Comment: @gurvinder372  His title is slightly miss-leading, he's not asking how to add a new object, more like add a new property to an object that's part of an array.

Comment: Some notes on language `{}` is an **object**, `[]` is an **array** `obj.something` `something` is a **property** of the **object** `obj`. What you call a template is a **constructor function**.

Comment: thank you all for comments! i am newbie and still learning javascript, so i must have misuse terms! thanks for pointing out! i have many things to learn haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to append is either use:

```
fruits[0]["taste"] = "good";
```

or:

```
fruits[0].taste = "good";
```

Answer (score 3):

I add an `taste` element to each object, and fill it with the value `"good"+ index of the element`. Here is a simple demo:

```js
var fruits = [];
fruits[0] = {name:"apple", stock:"1box"};
fruits[1] = {name:"banana", stock:"2box"};
fruits[2] = {name:"banana", stock:"3box"};
        
for(var index=0;index<fruits.length;index++){

    fruits[index].taste="good "+index;

}

console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: That's much better

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a property to existing object for each element in array is to itterate over the array and set the property to the desired value using

```
element[index].desiredProperty = desiredValue;
```

For example see following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/to70xe4j/1/